# Should I use core data at my iOS Push Notification App?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, notifications

I want to build an app that I can fetch notifications from server and save notification inside client devices for limitation only(50 Messages).But,I want to know that I need to use `CoreData` to store the data fetch from Server inside client app or not?If it is not,what should I use?I really need a hand to pick me up.Thanks.

**Note: I only want to store 50 Notifications only inside UITableView**

Any help?Please

Comment: interesting :) looking forward with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended use of core data is to store complex entities and large set of data with relationships. But since your data set is simple and small, it will be a better approach to use `Plist` files to store notification json.

**Plist downside over NSUserDefaults:** The downside of `Plist` files over `NSUserDefaults` is you have to write some extra code for file management (Copy/Read/Write).

**Plist upside over NSUserDefaults:** It separates your data from `NSUserDefaults` .plist file, which holds some other application related data.

If you don't want to code more then simply go with `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Coredata, it 's simple & easy
if your list notification have count > 50 , you can delete the first object and add new notification into last of list
when you open application, you can fetch Notification from coredata & sort with time,you can detech it was viewing or not with a variable is_view in notificationModel of coredata...

Comment: Thanks,i will wait for more answer too.Some use NSUserDefault.So,thanks for the suggestion.